# If the Landé $g$-factor of an electron is its magnetic moment due to its inherent quantum spin, and its spin is its magnetic moment, why isn't it 1?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, magnetic-moment

I was taught that the 'spin' of an elementary particle was its inherent, unalterable magnetic moment due to its physical spin, or angular momentum, that may or may not actually exist.

Therefore, if the quantum spin of a particle is not directly observable (because it probably doesn't exist, as such), but is measurable as its magnetic moment due to its seeming physical spin, how can its gyromagnetic ratio, or $g$-factor, be anything other than one?

What am I missing here?

Comment: The Landé $g$ factor of the electron is approximately $2$ because the spin of the electron is $1/2$. The spin of a particle is different from its spin magnetic moment, but the latter is derived from the first: $\vec{\mu}_s = -\frac{e}{2m}g\vec{S}$. Spin is not due to a rotation of the electron but it is an angular momentum, more precisely the intrinsic angular momentum of the electron.

Comment: *its magnetic moment due to its seeming physical spin...*  Start your reading at [Wikipedia's page on Spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_%28physics%29) but I've never seen or heard a really clear explanation and I tend to fall back on the math to explain where it comes from.  Dirac's equation was an eye-opener for me in this regard.  That Wikipedia page has a nice graphic showing how a point in space can spin without screwing up everything.